# How to use the heightForRowAtIndexPath method?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to use the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method in my `UITableViewController`. But when I try to override the method it says that it does not override any methods from its superclass.

Googling has led me to protocols, which seem to potentially be some part of the puzzle, but I'm still trying to understand how to use a protocol to use this method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code: (the problem method is at the very bottom)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class FruitsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 15
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)

        let busRef = rootRef.child("buses")
        busRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                let bus = snapshots[Int(indexPath.row)].key
                let busval = snapshots[Int(indexPath.row)].value as! String
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Bus \(bus) ------- \(busval)"
            }
        })

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Section \(section)"
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can either set a static height:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return 50
    } else {
        return 120
    }
}
```

Or use automatic dimension, with resizes every cell automatically according to its content:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks.  Setting the row height to custom in Main.storyboard and setting the height there does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Use following code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
    return 50.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
```

Replace it with:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
```

[I'm not sure whether you need the `override` but if you do the compiler will tell you so and you can put it back in.]

Comment: All you have to do in situations like this is look it up in the docs. For this function, the docs are here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview

Answer (score 0):

Remove `override` and the code should work. This is an optional protocol method--if you don't specify it, it will calculate the cell's height from the cell's view based on autolayout or the height set in prototype or static cells.

Comment: No - He can remove the "override" and the code will _compile_. But it won't _work_ because he has the wrong method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "override" and the following code should work

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 75.0
}
```